# Taylor Series expansion and radius of convergence for $e^z+e^{-z}+2cosz/4$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

So I did this by taking apart bits of that long equation:

$e^z=\sum z^n/n!$,

$e^{-z}=\sum(-z)^n/n!$

$2\cos z=e^{iz}+e^{-iz}$

So when we put these together as a Taylor Series, do we just add them all together since they belong to the same range of zero to infinity?  Additionally for the radius of convergence do we just take it by the ratio test?

Comment: If you've done one complex variable you can use the fact that the distance to closest pole is the radius of convergence.

Comment: Since neither cos or the complex exponentials has any poles at all, the convergence will be all over $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: I'm sorry I think I need a bit more clarification.  What would be the taylor series?

Comment: Just sum term by term from the individual series.

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine radius of convergence for power series is using distance to nearest pole in the complex plane.

Since each term is analytic, neither the individual terms nor the sum has any poles. So the convergence will be all over $\mathbb{C}$.

When determining the taylor expansion for a sum of functions you can just add the expansions for the individual terms.